# How to assign variable's value to a constant?

Tags: ruby, variables, constants

Writing an assignment such as `CONST = some_var` will raise `SyntaxError` as Constant in ruby could not be reassigned.

But in some cases, I want to hold the current variable's **value** in a constant and lock it there.

For example, when I initialize an instance from a class, I want to lock the passed in value within the instance. How should I do it the right way in ruby? (following is a illegal code in ruby trying to realize it, you get the idea)

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(status)
    STATUS = status # it is illegal now
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ruby constants are expected to preserve the same value, it's a [recommendation](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html), not a must:

> A Ruby constant is like a variable, except that its value is supposed to remain constant for the duration of the program. The Ruby interpreter does not actually enforce the constancy of constants, but it does issue a warning if a program changes the value of a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Use an instance variable with a getter and no setter. Like this:

```
class SomeClass
  attr_reader :status
  def initialize(status)
    @status = status
  end
end
```

Now you can use your object like this:

```
>> a = SomeClass.new(5)
=> #<SomeClass:0x108c80218 @status=5>
>> a.status
=> 5
>> a.status=7
NoMethodError: undefined method `status=' for #<SomeClass:0x108c80218 @status=5>
from (irb):9
```